# Как изменить свойства объекта в массиве

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Сейчас пытаюсь реализовать изменения свойств объекта в массиве но не получается.
К чему я пришел:
Дизайн:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Компонент в котором происходит вызов функции и отрисовка результата а именно "Взрослые"

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
              <div className="GuestsItem__calc">
                        <div className="GuestsItem__minus" onClick={() => chageOldMinus(item.id)}>
                        </div>
                        <div className="GuestsItem__num">
                            {item.old}
                        </div>
                        <div className="GuestsItem__plus" onClick={() => chageOldPlus(item.id)}>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Компонент в котором содержаться функции изменения объекта и сам объект:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    const [GuestsData, setGuestsData] = useState([
        {
            id: 0,
            old: 1,
            child: 1
        }
    ]);
    const chageOldPlus = (el) => {
        console.log(GuestsData);
        GuestsData.forEach((item) => {
            item.id === el
                ?
                item.old++
                :
                item.text = item.text
        })
    }
    const chageOldMinus = (el) => {
        console.log(GuestsData);
        GuestsData.forEach((item) => {
            item.id === el
                ?
                item.old--
                :
                item.text = item.text
        })
    }
```

Что происходит при таком использовании:
В консоли меняется нужное мне свойство, а на сайте нет.
При этом есть два странных поведения:

- Если например добавлю console.log и зайду на сайт число поменяется на правильное, т.е. при изменения кода нужное свойство измененяется.
- В консоли, если нажимать на "+" и не раскрывать объекты, то число меняться не будет, если каждый раскрывать то в консоли будет видно изменения объекта.

Очень тяжело объяснил, надеюсь суть понятна

Comment: Вам надо менять состояние, используя **setGuestsData**, а вы мутируете текущее, поэтому реакт не видит изменений

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В консоли меняется нужное мне свойство, а на сайте нет. При этом есть два странных поведения ...

Ничего странного как раз нет. Просто ты не верно меняешь стейт. При твоей организации данных нужно менять весь массив и в нем целиком нужный объект.

Вот набросал некую принципиальную модель аналогичного изменения...

```js
//
function Act({val, type, act}) {
  const title = type === 'old' ? 'Взрослые' : 'Дети'
  return <div>
    <span className='title'>{title}</span>
    <button onClick={_ => act(type, -1)}>-</button>
    <span className='value'>{val}</span>
    <button onClick={_ => act(type, 1)}>+</button>    
  </div>
}
//
function Item({data, act}) {
  const id = data.id
  // вот тут нужно стейту возвращать новый массив с обновленным объектом
  const inc = (type, v) => {
    act(old => old.map(o => o.id === id ? {...o, [type]: o[type] + v} : o))
  }
  return <li>
    <Act val={data.old} type={'old'} act={inc} />
    <Act val={data.child} type={'child'} act={inc} />
  </li>
}
//
function App() {
  const [arr, setArr] = React.useState([
    {
      id: 0,
      old: 1,
      child: 1
    }
  ])
  return <ul>
    {arr.map(o => <Item key={o.id} data={o} act={setArr} />)}
  </ul>
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);
root.render(<App />);
```

```css
.title {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
}
.value {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="like_button_container"></div>
```